# Finding Common Node for given two nodes in neo4j through java

Tags: java, neo4j

I am developing a Question Answering application using Neo4j in Java.
For that I need to find intermediate nodes between given two nodes through any relationship.

For Example given Graph:

```
A - x -> C
B - y -> C
```

Therefore if given [A,B] nodes, the output should be [C], because it is connected to both A and B through relationship x and y respectively.
Is this possible using Java driver of neo4j.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If A and B have ids 1 and 2, the cypher query you want looks something like:

```
MATCH A -- C -- B
WHERE id(A)=1 AND id(B)=2
RETURN C
```

Make this query from your Java setup and you should be good to go

Comment: How can we use direct cypher queries in java. Didnt know about that.

Comment: It depends how you're using Java, but [the java embedded documentation](http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/tutorials-cypher-java.html)